# Document management: select individual pieces of multiple documents to create a new word document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

This is sort of a follow-up to a previous question I asked.  I work at a school and we need to create assignments for the same courses every semester.  Over the course of many years we have generated a large number of previous assignment questions.

I have created Word documents that group all of the questions relating to a particular topic.  For the purposes of this post, let's assume that I have one document for "questions about addition" and another for "questions about multiplication".

Frequently, we make assignments that span multiple topics, only because of how lecture scheduling works out.  Therefore, I may want to create an assignment that includes questions from both the "addition" and "multiplication" master documents.

Here is what would be *ideal* - I'd like to create a template with a bunch of input forms.  I will first input how many questions I want, then I will get to select certain questions from, ideally, drop-down menus.  For instance, I might want to create a new document with 3 questions.  Then I would like to see 3 "new question" input fields.  I'd like to be able to choose a topic, a difficulty (easy, medium, or hard), and then get a drop down menu of all questions that fit those criteria.  I would like to select one question from that drop down, which should automatically populate my word document by copying and pasting from the appropriate master document.

My questions:

a) Is this even possible, using only Word?  It is important that it's only word since this has to be easily maintainable on school systems and the only constant is that we always have access to MS Word.

b) If it's possible, I understand that I'm describing a fairly basic SQL database.  Is it even worth creating such a monster in Word?  At the moment all we're doing is a manual search of the master documents and copy-and-pasting if we find something we like.  It works but it's not great

Comment: MS Word isn't designed for document manipulations of the sort you're describing. IMHO, your best solution is to abandon Word and move to DTP system that understands the requirements of persons doing serious technical documentation. FrameMaker, LaTex, and MadCap Flare are the packages that come to mind. FrameMaker has been the go-do tool for persons creating long technical docs for 30+ years. Flare hasn't been around as long, and true, it's primary use is creating help systems, but I and many others use it to single-source technical documentation as help and book form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible and you will need a macro enabled template (.dotm format) to do it.

Each of your variable pieces such as Level 1 to 3 Multiple Choice (level is degree of difficulty) are stored in the template as AutoText files or possibly separate text files. From a custom built VBA based UserForm that displays when the template is launched, you make the various selections and then click a button to begin. The custom VBA code in the template then assembles the document based on the selected specification.

To see conceptually how this might work, do a web search on **AuthorTec Find and Highlight**. That Word add-in searches a document for customizable words and phrases, for example search for a custom list of adverbs. The custom lists can be setup by student grade level, and a student paper would then be analyzed for the vocabulary level they are writing in.

If you take that concept, as shown in the add-in I just mentioned, of making a selection from a VBA UserForm dialog and then the appropriate custom list of Multiple Choice questions appear in the listbox on the form, the selections can then be taken an placed into a Word document.